# LookupField (Multiple) is not updating through c# code

Tags: sharepoint-server, spfieldlookupvalue

In my project we have a SPLookupField developed through XML as,

```
<Field ID="{67146805-10A0-473F-971C-0B42BD36C2C9}" Name="My Reports" StaticName="Reports" Group="Custom Columns" Type="LookupMulti" DisplayName="My Reports" Description="List of associated reports" Mult="TRUE" 
List="Lists/MyList" DisplaceOnUpgrade="TRUE" Sortable="TRUE" ShowField="Title" Required="True" />
```

This field is mapped to Title field of a Document Library named Source List.

Notice Name of the field has space between two words as "My Reports". Ya even I wondered but this field is deployed in SharePoint portal and working fine.
I can edit the list item in List Library and change the lookup value.
I can retrieve field's value through code but what I am not able to do is update the lookup value of this field.

I have a list named Master Reports in which this field is being used. When I change the value in LookupField (Title of the document) in Source List it doesn't reflect the updated value in Master Reports list in which this lookup field is being used. It doesn't show the updated value in Master Reports but when I click on the value it shows me the updated value. In List UI it doesn't refresh and show the updated value.
I have tried following codes to change it,

```
SPFieldLookupValue sflv = new SPFieldLookupValue(50, "Test Value_changed");
SPFieldLookupValueCollection newReps = new SPFieldLookupValueCollection();
newReps.Add(sflv);

SPFieldLookup field = masterReport.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("My Reports") as SPFieldLookup;
masterReportItem[field.Id] = newReps;
masterReportItem.Web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
masterReportItem.Update();
```

I even tried following,

```
masterReport[field.Id] = newReps[0].LookupId;
```

and,

```
masterReport["My Reports"] = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0};#{1}", newReps[0].LookupId.ToString(), newReps[0].LookupValue);
```

But nothing updates the value in Master Reports list library.

Funny thing is if I update the field through Powershell it works fine.

```
 $mi["My Reports"] = "1;#Test_New1"
 $mi.Web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = $true
 $mi.Update()
 $mi["My Reports"]

   LookupId LookupValue
   -------- -----------
          1 Test_New1
```

Please let me know if I am missing something. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Guys,
Let me make it more clear actually, I am changing the Lookup value in source list (to which this lookup field is mapped to, Title field of a document library) and this field is added in a target list. So when I change the title of the document it should reflect the change in target list. But in target list it doesn't show the updated value. As Title is a link field so when I click on the title link of that document in target list it shows me view properties page of that document from Source Document Library. In that view prop page it shows me updated value.

So that's the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The right way to set the value is:

```
listItem["field"] = new SPFieldLookupValue(1, "text"); //the ID must exist
```

If you dont have one of the parameters, you will have to perform a "query" to get it.

```
SPFieldLookupValue fieldLookupValue = new SPFieldLookupValue(item["FieldName"].ToString());
int lookupID = fieldLookupValue.LookupId;
string lookupValue = fieldLookupValue.LookupValue;
```

If you need multiple values the answer is

```
SPFieldLookupValueCollection fieldValues = new
SPFieldLookupValueCollection();

fieldValues.Add (new SPFieldLookupValue(1, "SomeValue1"));  // add other field values or in loop

item["lookupmultiField"] = fieldValues;
item.Update();
```

try that, greetings

Comment: This is the answer.  Lookup Fields are tied by the originating lookup field ID.

Comment: Hi Marco,
Thanks for the response. I checked and can tell there is no constructor accepting 1 parameter ID as integer. One argument constructor accepts string value which is lookup value and not lookup id.

Comment: Hi Sayed, you are right. I edit my answer.

Comment: Still it didn't work. Please check my comment to the original post.

Comment: I'm quite sure that this is the answer. Check if the values exist in the Parent List.
In your post you mention a SPFieldLookupValueCollection is this field a lookupField with multiple values?
Provide us the error

Comment: Hi Marco,
When I change any value in Source Document library (Title field), which this Multi lookup field is mapped to, change is not reflected in list in which this lookup field is used.

Document Library - Title Field
Document 1

List Library with Lookup Field as My Reports
Document 1

After update,

Document Library - Title Field
Document 2

List Library with Lookup Field as My Reports
Document 1

As My Reports field is link title field so when I click on Document 1 in list it shows me updated properties of doc from Document Library. So text is not changed in List Library

Comment: Lets see...
Do you have a list that has a field of type lookup which reads a data from a library of documents and when you update this value in the document library this change this change is not reflected in the lista?

Answer (score 0):

Hi the lookup field accepts the item id as parameter,try with below code

```
listItem["field"] =GetLookup("Text to update");

private SPFieldLookupValue GetLookup(string Name)
    {
        SPFieldLookupValue spLookupName = null;
        try
        {
            SPList lst = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists.TryGetList("List");
            if (lst != null)
            {
                SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title' /><Value Type='Text'>" + Name + "</Value></Eq></Where>";

                SPListItemCollection listColl = lst.GetItems(query);
                if (listColl.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (SPListItem item in listColl)
                    {
                        if (item["Title"] != null)
                        {
                           spLookupName = new SPFieldLookupValue(Convert.ToInt32(item["ID"]), Convert.ToString(item["Title"]));                                
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            WriteToLogFile("GetLookup() : " + ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
        }
        return spLookupName ;
    }
```

Comment: Hi Sunil,
I have tried this as well but it doesn't work.

Comment: Where List is the Parent list used for lookup

Comment: Hi Sunil,
Please see my comment to Marco on Nov 18 at 10:25